# Filling Datagrid from separate form without removing data

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, dataview

I select a value in the combo-box in the form Addsubject().

This takes all the values from my database with the same value and adds them to the DGV.

Only issue is when i try to add a second value from the combo-box it replaces the first.

Form addsubject() has a button that when clicked takes the data and places it in the form1 dgv.

```
 Private Sub btnAddSub_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddSub.Click
    Dim comboboxvalue As String
    comboboxvalue = "'" & CBClass.SelectedItem & "'"
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Select * From class Where ClassCode=" & comboboxvalue
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\ProjectDatabase.mdb"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource

    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, MyConn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Class")
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    Form1.dgv.DataSource = view

End Sub
```

**Images of the issue**

Pre-button click
[image]
Post-Click
[image]
 New value and button click
[image]

Comment: That little dialog is at least partly to blame (and it isnt even mentioned).  Is it adding to the CBO?  Why do you run a query for the CBO when you click a Dialog button?  A Cbo selects only one item, so it is not clear what `second value from the combo-box` means.

Comment: The combo-box is how the user chooses the class code. Then my code should find in my access database the the record for the chosen class code. Then the record from access is then placed into the dgv.

Comment: but the code shown is not for a combobox selection changed.  it appears to be for when they click ADD on that dialog

Comment: Wouldn't the code at the top be enough? comboboxvalue = "'" & CBClass.SelectedItem & "'"

Comment: My problem is when a new value is selected it doesn't create a new row for it to go into. Just overwrites the current one.

Comment: The dialog seems to be the means to populate (add) items to the CBO that has nothing to do with the user selecting a new value in the CBO.  Then, a totally separate issue is that the query only looks for one class code, it creates a new DS, DT, DA replacing the previous.  So it is working as expected.  (rather than type in classcodes, the CBO could be populated from the DB: "SELECT ClassCode from class" and used as the DS for the control

Comment: The thing is I want all the pieces of data that come from the database when i select just the class code. And the problem with you suggestion is that I dont want all the classcodes. I want to be able to pick and choose which ones are applicable.

Comment: Ok,  If you dont get it you dont get it.  Your code is not set up to append pr accumulate.  The code shown does not fire when the user makes a selection in the CBO, it is assigned to a *different event* entirely.

Comment: First major project for my school coursework so Im still learning and dont grasp all the concepts full yet. Thank you for trying though :)